Why Interpolation using DCT looks different than interpolation using DFT?
I am trying to simulate the behavior of DFT and DCT interpolation by zero padding in frequency domain. It seems their is a difference in the behavior and DCT output appears to be much smoother than what I am getting using DFT. I know the DFT output may be explained by sinc interpolation but I am really not sure how can the DCT outputs be explained. I have included the code here. For example, in the output figures shown, I can see the middle portion of DFT output graph representing the zero-value portion of input a is showing oscillatory behaviors probably due to the sinc interpolation. But the output graph for DCT for the same portion is much smoother.
Why naturally DCT output is looking better and smooth than FFT? How does this differ from the sinc interpolation effect caused by taking DFT?
a=[100 150 0 0 0 90 145 70]
b=dct(a);
c=[b zeros(1,56)];
d=idct(c);
figure(1);plot((d))
a=[100 150 0 0 0 90 145 70];
b=dct(a);
c=[b zeros(1,56)];
d=idct(c);
figure(1);plot((d));title('Plot for DCT Interpolation')
For DFT:
a=[100 150 0 0 0 90 145 70];
b=fft(a);
c=[b zeros(1,56)];
d=ifft(c);
figure(2);plot(abs(d));title('Plot for DFT Interpolation')


[]
